# How to make setState update before other function with useState

Tags: react-native

I am building a form to confirm the pin code of telephone number after user entered it.

I started code with

`const [code, setCode] = useState("");`

and I use Smooth pin code input like that

```
<SmoothPinCodeInput
          cellStyle={{
            width: 50,
            borderBottomWidth: 2,
            borderColor: "gray"
          }}
          cellStyleFocused={{
            borderColor: "black"
          }}
          animated
          onFulfill={() => 
            {
              setIsCodeCompleted(true)
              confirmUserPin()
            }
          }
          value={code}
          onTextChange={code => setCode(code)}
        />
```

the problem is that `setCode(code)` works after `confirmUsePin()` that is called with `onFilfill()` so my pin code is 4 numbers but only 3 numbers get sent, this happend because setCode doesn't update code immediately.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, I used `useEffect` so every time length of `code` is 4 it calls the function. Here is how

```
useEffect( () =>{
    if(code.length == 4){
      confirmUserPin()
    }
  }, [code] )
```

Comment: I've been working on this for an hour
You solved it nicely

Comment: i try slove it with "ref"